# Naming small storage classes in java

Tags: java, naming-conventions, naming

i often have in java projects a lot of small helper("storage") classes like
2-Tuple, 3-Tuple, Point, .. (think you know what i mean)
Classes that mostly only have class variables, a constructor and getters/setters.

And in my current project, i wanted to store those small classes, that are often used in a lot of other classes in the project in a seperate package. But i do not really know how to name it (my motherlanguage is not english, but code should be for english readers.)

Hope you can give me an answer on this little questions.

Greetings
:)

Comment: btw no need to code your own tuples. see http://javatuples.org/

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I've decided to use com.xx.util.data as pacakge name and the classname:eg "Tuple".   Mixture of the answers, but for me it looks the best:D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different people would name these differently as the names are a matter of personal choice.

A few options:

1. If the storage classes conform to the Javabeans conventions, you could add the suffix "Bean" eg PointBean
2. I have also seen a suffix of "DO" or "VO" being used to denote a "data object" or "value object". eg PointDO
3. You could leave the class name as is eg Point. However if you feel that it does not convey the fact it is a storage class, try to make the package name convey that fact eg
   com.xyz.valueobjects.Point 
   or 
   com.xyz.dataobjects.Point
   or
   com.xyz.storage.Point

Personally I like to use style #3.

Comment: Naming a class "SomethingBean" seems as redundant as naming it "SomethingClass"

Answer (score 4):

I'd stick those kinds of classes in a `*.util` package.

Comment: To be clear: `util` is a conventional shorthand for "utility" -- data structure classes are commonly put into such packages.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with something like:

`utils` or the more verbose `utilities`

you can then break that down further if you need to:

`utils.data` for data-related utility classes, for example.

Additionally, there's a question here on whether to pluralise or not: [Naming convention for utility classes in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676704/naming-convention-for-utility-classes-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

For your information the "storage classes" you are referring to are called Java Beans.  Using the popular model view controller design pattern; these would be your model.  So lets say you want to put them in a package called model and the domain name of your company is `mycompany.com`, then the propper java naming convention would be `com.mycompany.model;` add this line as the first line of code (before any import statements) to all of your Java bean classes:

```
package com.mycompany.model;
```

You must also move your Java bean files into a folder structure that is the same.  Lets say the file with your main method is in the directory `/%ProjectHome%/`, then your Java Beans go in a folder `/%ProjectHome%/com/mycompany/model/`

To compile these files you will now have to change to your `/%ProjectHome%/` directory then type javac `com/mycompany/model/*.java`

Then you will be able to import these files from your other java classes by typing

```
import com.mycompany.model.*;
```

Also note, that the Java convention for package names is all lower case, as not to clash with the name space of Class names.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The OP wasn't really talking about logical models of the application domain, but simple, lightweight, "anonymous" data structures that don't really have any logic or meaning on their own.

Comment: My take was that they wanted to 'know how to name' java packages.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're doing is using objects purely for storing data (no behaviour). And since you're talking about tuples, I assume these are used for transferring data to/from your database, so perhaps just "data objects"?