# Meaning of "common" in file names

Tags: file, naming, conventions

Sometimes files in projects are named "commons".

What does it exactly mean? Here is an example:

[image: obnoxious picture of text]

Comment: It means that the code in the common file or directory is common to other pieces of code i.e. the code is used by (or shared with) other functions/methods.

Answer (score 2):

The names include *common* because they contain code shared between several parts of a project or different projects and used commonly, eg. functions used in multiple classes. A well-known example are the [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/) libraries.

It's useful to be consistent in naming the files and also keep them cohesive. Related is *utility* (eg. see [Naming convention for utility classes in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2676704)).

Sources:

This has also been asked on [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/251192) before. From the highest-voted [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/251194) (by a now deleted user):

> While writing code, one often finds themselves with a common set of tools/classes/libraries that are used again and again across multiple projects.

Dave Cheney in [Avoid package names like base, util, or common](https://dave.cheney.net/2019/01/08/avoid-package-names-like-base-util-or-common) (January 2019):

> Packages with names like `base` or `common` are often found when functionality common to two or more related facilities, for example common types between a client and server or a server and its mock, has been refactored into a separate package.